# Failed to install NuGet package 'SonarAnalyzer.CSharp' for project. Message: This package can only be installed on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sonarqube, visual-studio-2017, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and created Test Project to bind with SonarQube server using SonarLint. When I clicked on project to bind, I am getting below error.

"Binding solution to SonarQube project: Discovering solution projects
   Included projects:
   * TestSonar\TestSonar.csproj
   Excluded projects:
   * TestSonar.Tests\TestSonar.Tests.csproj
   You can change the exclusion options via the SonarLint project-level context menu i.e. Solution Explorer -> Select project(s)
Binding solution to SonarQube project: Download quality profile(s):
   Successfully downloaded quality profile. Name: 'Sonar way', Key: 'cs-sonar-way-54843', Language: 'C#'
   Installing NuGet package 'SonarAnalyzer.CSharp' for project 'TestSonar'

**Failed to install NuGet package 'SonarAnalyzer.CSharp' for project 'TestSonar'. Message: This package can only be installed on Visual Studio 2015.**

Binding solution to SonarQube project: Generating project rule sets

Binding solution to SonarQube project: Not all NuGet packages were installed. 
Please see output above for more information."

Comment: Please, update your question to specify your SonarC#, SonarLint and SonarQube versions.

Answer (score 2):

SonarC# started supporting Visual Studio 2017 after version 5.6, I guess you are using older version of the plugin and if you update to the latest, the message will disappear.